# __weak + __block is it Ok to use both for a variable

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, weak-references

In ARC, the following line of code is meaningful? Please confirm.

```
__block __weak MyViewController_iPad *blockSelf = self;
```

This is not throwing any errors. Don't know why.

Consider the following example.

```
NSArray* keyWords = someArray;

[keyWords enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                keyWords = nil;
            }];
```

In this case do we need to specify both attributes under ARC. This is unusual thats why I had this doubt.

```
__weak __block NSArray* keyWords = someArray;

[keyWords enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                    keyWords = nil;
                }];
```

The above code snippet is correct? Please confirm.

Comment: What errors are you expecting? What do you think it means / will do? What do you want to use it for?

Comment: Hi Wain , I added the example.

Answer (score 3):

You should use __block if you want to change variable value in block.

e.g:

```
__block BOOL result = NO;
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  ...
  result = YES;
  ...
});
```

You should use __weak if you want to avoid retain cycles.

e.g.

```
__weak typeof(self) wself = self;
self.foobarCompletion = ^{
  ...
  wself.foo = YES;
  ...
};
```

You can combine them if there is a need.

Answer (score 2):

In your edit, you provided some sample code:

```
__weak __block NSArray* keyWords = someArray;

[keyWords enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    keyWords = nil;
}];
```

In this situation `__weak` is neither needed nor appropriate. Typically you use `__weak` in conjunction with blocks to avoid strong reference cycles. But no such cycle exists here, so `__weak` is not needed.

Just use `__block`, remove `__weak`, and you're done.

(Having said that, this example represents other issues, namely that you really shouldn't be changing `keyWords` while enumerating through the array. If you tell us what you're trying to do with this code we can undoubtedly show you a better way to achieve it.)

Comment: Thank you @Rob. Yes we shouldn't modify "keywords" while editing. Sorry I gave a raw example.   But as per Apple doc "[obj doSomething: ^{ [obj something]; } ];" is an example of type retain cycle if keywords is of global scope of if "self". Am I right ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @arango_86 - If `doSomething` uses the block and then releases it (ie, just lets it fall out of scope), then there's no strong reference cycle beyond that point. But if `doSomething` takes that closure and saves it as a property of `obj`, then a strong reference cycle could result. It just depends upon what `doSomething` is doing. It would be exceptionally unusual, though, to declare a `__block` variable that is also `__weak`. I'm hard-pressed to come up with realistic scenarios that I'd even contemplate doing that.